# Is there an option how to pass relative path to System property javax.net.ssl.trustStore

Tags: java, file, security, properties, java-security

Hello is there an option how to pass relative path of my truststore to java System property **javax.net.ssl.trustStore** ?.

I'm trying this code `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",configuration.getProperty("trustStore.location"));`  with property in properties file set to `trustStore.location=security/cc.jks` but it doesn't work for me. If i specify absolute path in `trustStore.location` property it works.

Thanks.

Comment: iam reading keystore from same location check `InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configuration.getProperty("trustStore.location"));` and i don't have any problem

Comment: When you say "relative path" -- relative to what? My understanding is that a non-absolute trust/key store location will be taken relative to the current working directory. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want. Use relative path  to my current working directory.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know. I can only guess that, at run-time, your working directory isn't where you expect it to be.

Comment: is there any other option how to do this? like using cmd arguments or maven properties etc.?